# Cannot pin Android plugin version in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

Because of [the bug](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8444) in `firebase_auth` plugin I'm getting Java memory error reports in Crashlytics. So I want to pin `firebase-auth` Android plugin to `20.0.4` version.

I added `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'` buildscript dependency to `android/build.gradle`. I also specified Android plugin version in locally cached Flutter plugin's `build.gradle` with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'` (version was not specified here).

I also tried Android project clean and Flutter clean. But the errors are still present because plugin version is not changed. I checked my APK - it has `firebase-auth.properties` file with the following content:

```
version=21.0.3
client=firebase-auth
firebase-auth_client=21.0.3
```

Why is it still `21.0.3` and how to change that?

**UPDATE:**

I tried *up*grading to `21.0.5` and it works, but *down*grade does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is `firebase_core` is using *Firebase Android BoM*, and BoM version specifies the versions of all Firebase Android packages.

I discovered it by running the following command from `android` directory:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

So, the right way to pin Firebase Auth Android plugin in a Flutter app is to pin `firebase_core` Flutter plugin. I pinned it to `1.13.1` and it worked. Also had to downgrade `firebase_crashlytics` because it could not compile with the old `firebase_core`.